# Write permissions denied even after 777

Tags: python, cgi, permission-denied

I am running a python CGI script which must create a video at a directory location.

Platform : `Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit`

Python Version : `2.7.6`

The script is being run by the user : `www-data`

I have a directory `mydir`.
The permissions to `mydir` are `777` (recursive). This directory is owned by user: `www-data` and group `www-data`.
The Python script creates a new directory in a sub-directory of `mydir`, but there is an Exception raised:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'path/to/file.ext'
```

I observed that the new directory which was created, surprisingly had the following state:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 me   me   4096 <Timestamp> newdir
```

When I checked earlier the process was being run by `www-data` but now the folder is owned by the current user I am logged into. (indicated by `'me'` here).
Moreover all permissions are set except check the others permissions `r-x`. NO WRITE PERMISSIONS. That justifies the exception raised.

I tried to do a `os.umask(0000)` as well as `os.chmod('mydir',0777)`. First one did not have any effect. Second one, I don't have permissions somehow. Can somebody please help. This issue is real irritating. What am I missing here?

**Note**: The python file is triggered as follows: A `cronjob` calls a `PHP` file which after some processing then sends a post request to the `Python` script.

**EDIT**: Please let me know if the solution by @MattDMo works (I won't be testing it as I have changed my approach). I will mark it as accepted if somebody finds it working.

Comment: I already have searched around. But not found a solution

Comment: Is the `cron` job being run by `www-data`?

Comment: Are you using curl or php in the cron job, that can change the user that is running the entire jobset.

Comment: @MattDMo No, `cron` job is not run by `www-data`. I observed that if I set `cron` job from the current logged in user, folder is owned by that user. I also ran `cron` job using `root`, then folder was owned by `root`.

Comment: @thebwt I am using `php` to call the file in `cron` job. I see the owner changing, because when I write the log file, it is owned by `www-data` but new folder is owned by the user who created cron job `me` or `root`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need to do is edit your `crontab` and add `www-data` as the user:

```
*/5 * * * * www-data php call_python.php
```

This can also be done from the command line by running `crontab` with the `-u` option, which specifies the name of the user whose crontab is to be changed:

```
sudo crontab -u www-data -e
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually changed my approach. I cut off the `CGI` part from my system. I did some refactoring. Now I am directly calling the python script, ported the `PHP` operations to the `Python` itself.

Comment: I will not be marking the above answer as accepted as I have not tested it. If somebody finds this to work, please let me know.